# Selenium Explicit Wait not working when clicked on submit button (where page loads for 25 seconds)

Tags: java, selenium

When clicked on book bus on cleartrip.com website for the round trip journey and the explicit wait is used, then I am getting NoSuchElementException or StaleElementException but same if I am using it at a different place in the same class it works. (I am using Thread. sleep currently which I don't want to use)

```
    Below is the code I have used explicit wait's instance and called a method as visibilityOf(WebElement). When used thread.sleep
    programs works smoothly.
```

Below is gitHub link for the code, Refer line no 64 to 67 on this code

https://github.com/bharadiya/TestNGTutorials/blob/master/src/Scenarios/OnClearTrip.java

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void waitUntil(long time, TimeUnit unit, RemoteWebDriver driver, Function isTrue,long pollingUnits) {
        try {
            FluentWait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver).withTimeout(time, unit).pollingEvery(pollingUnits, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
            wait.until(isTrue);
        } catch (ErrorPageException ex) {
            throw ex;
        } catch (AjaxError ex) {
            throw ex;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Error in wait until for " + UrlHelper.getCurrentUrl() + ".Reason : " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
        }
    }

-> I/P for the above function:
say: 
time -> 15
unit -> Seconds
driver -> Selenium driver instance
isTrue -> ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(el) (predicate) 
pollingUnits -> 400 (Millisecs mentioned in the code)
```